# How to change exponential number format to the floating-point format in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a string in Perl that contains a small number:
$num = "0.00000001";

When I make a numeric operation on it, it becomes number in exponential format:
$num = $num * 100;
print "$num\n";

The result is: 1e-06

The question is,
how to get this number be printed in floating-point format, i.e. 0.000001.

I know I can do it for specific number with sprintf("%.6f", $num),
but I'd like to have a generic solution,
so I won't have to determine each time how many digits to show after the decimal point
(like 6 in the above sprintf example)

Comment: Don't specify the number of decimal places in the format specification, i.e. just use `sprintf("%f", ...)`

Answer (score 6):

When you apply a numeric operation to `$num`, it becomes a floating-point number.  `1e-06` and `0.000001` are textual representations of that number; the stored value doesn't distinguish between them.

If you simply print or stringify the number, it uses a default format which, as you've seen, results in `"1e-06"`.  Using `sprintf` with a format of `"%f"` will give you a reasonable result; `sprintf("%f", $num)` yields `"0.000001"`.

But the `"%f"` format can lose information.  For example:

```
$num = "0.00000001";
printf("%f\n", $num);
```

prints:

```
0.000000
```

You say you want to print without having to determine each time how many digits to show after the decimal point.  *Something* has to make that determination, and there's no universally correct way to do so.  The obvious thing to do is print just the significant digits, omitting trailing zeros, but that presents some problems.  How many digits do you print for `1.0/3.0`, whose decimal representation has an infinite sequence of `3`s?  And `0.00000001` can't be represented exactly in binary floating-point:

```
$num = "0.00000001";
printf("%f\n", $num);    
printf("%.78f\n", $num);
```

prints:

```
0.000000
0.000000010000000000000000209225608301284726753266340892878361046314239501953125
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [rodents of unusual size](http://p3rl.org/bigrat):

```
$ perl -Mbigrat -E'$num = 0.00000001; $num *= 100; say $num'
0.000001
```

Comment: Using Perl 5.12, I get `1/1000000`.  Using Perl 5.14, I get `0.000001`.

Comment: The distro is dual-lived. You can upgrade to 0.29 independently and see whether it helps.

Comment: Years later: with Perl 5.34, bigrat 0.51, I get `1/1000000`